# Rails' excessive DESCRIBE and SHOW TABLES on partitioned mySQL tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We see a ton of `SHOW TABLES;` and `` DESCRIBE `table name`; `` queries in production - not just on Rails server restarts. We noticed it was only for our partitioned tables. This is on Rails 3.1.1 - not tested on other versions.

When testing in dev console (with `cache_classes = true`), we noticed for partitioned models, Rails runs one  `SHOW TABLES;` and one `` DESCRIBE `table name`; `` for **each record returned** from any find method.

For example, if `items` is partitioned, and `Item.limit(5)` returns 5 records, the mySQL log looks like this (Note: the `SHOW TABLES`'s AND `DESCRIBE`'s aren't included in the Rails log):

```
SELECT  `items`.* FROM `items`  LIMIT 5;
SHOW TABLES;
DESCRIBE `items`;
SHOW TABLES;
DESCRIBE `items`;
SHOW TABLES;
DESCRIBE `items`;
SHOW TABLES;
DESCRIBE `items`;
SHOW TABLES;
DESCRIBE `items`;
```

That's pretty insane.

Non-partitioned models don't do any `SHOW TABLES`'s nor `DESCRIBE`'s, except of course when starting a Rails server. It looks like if an AR model isn't aware of its primary key, AR has to get the schema each time an object of that model is instantiated.

If `cache_classes` is set to `true`, you would think Rails would / should cache the schema for even a model without a known primary key. But it doesn't.

You wouldn't think that `SHOW TABLES` and `DESCRIBE` would have any real impact on a system, but we found out with enough traffic, the concurrent reads due to these extra queries on one partitioned table caused real performance problems.

How can we get rid of these queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [composite_primary_keys](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/) gem saved the day. I remember seeing this gem a long time ago, but never used it. The intended features of the gem will definitely simplify our partitioned models when we start using those methods, but a side-effect of using the gem was more important:

Just telling Rails the `primary_key` of each partitioned table removed all the `SHOW TABLES`'s and `DESCRIBE`'s, which brought us well below the explode-due-to-read-concurrency threshold and improved response times.